# How to extract coordinates from a string into textbox or variable?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

How do I extract coordinate values from a string into a text box or variable?

Like in the example given below, im manually entering the top left and bottom right coordinates of a rectangle, I want it to be copied automatically. How do I achieve this? Please help.

[image]

Comment: That image doesn't help much.  What specific data do you have, and what specific output do you want?  What have you tried?  If you have a string, have you tried parsing that string?  (There are a variety of methods on the `string` object to help with that.)  If something else, what?

Comment: You need to add code

Comment: I tried string.split, but it created a new string without { and ,.
im trying to split the string and assign the X and Y values to new variables each.

Comment: what does your string contains?

Comment: @user3177511: *"I tried string.split"* - Not according to your question you didn't.  If you tried something and it didn't work, ask about that.  *"but it created a new string"* - Strings are immutable.  All modifications to string values result in new strings.  What specifically did you *try*?  What was the input?  What was the observed output?  What was the *expected* output?  *Why?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using *regular expressions* in order to *match* them, e.g.

```
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 string source = @"{X=113,Y=171}{X=160,Y=171}{X=160,Y=51}{X=113,Y=51}";

 // We assume each coordinate being an integer value 
 Regex pattern = new Regex(
   @"\{\s*X\s*=\s*(?<x>-?[0-9]+)\s*\,\s*Y\s*=\s*(?<y>-?[0-9]+)\s*\}",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

 // Let's take 4 top matches
 var data = pattern
  .Matches(source)
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => new {
    x = match.Groups["x"].Value,
    y = match.Groups["y"].Value,
  })
  .Take(4)
  .ToArray();

if (data.Length == 4) {
  leftTextBox.Text   = data[3].x;
  topTextBox.Text    = data[3].y;
  rightTextBox.Text  = data[1].x; 
  bottomTextBox.Text = data[1].y; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitry. This worked perfectly. Im the director of travancore systems, a company based in India specializing in the development of thermal imaging and other vision systems related products. Would you be interested in freelancing work?

Comment: @user3177511: Thank you for the proposal! Yes, it would be interesting for me to work with images (recognition, vision systems)

Comment: Plz send me a test mail at info@travancoresys.com